# Visual Studio Code + WordPress + Docker: VS Code Not Sourcing Apache envvars File

Tags: wordpress, docker, visual-studio-code, docker-compose, vscode-remote

I do volunteer work on a WordPress site for our local non-profit radio station, and with a total website overhaul in the works I decided to set up WordPress with Docker and Visual Studio Code's Remote Development features since I enjoy that setup so much in my day job doing Python/Django development.

It's all working OK with the usual environment-specific tweaks, and when I run docker-compose up from a terminal it runs fine.

When I run things in VS Code's remote development environment, however, it doesn't start Apache automatically. That isn't a huge deal, but when I try to start Apache in a terminal in VS Code by running `apache2 -D FOREGROUND` I get this error:

`apache2: Syntax error on line 80 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: DefaultRuntimeDir must be a valid directory, absolute or relative to ServerRoot`

If i run `source /etc/apache2/envvars` that fixes the issue, so not a huge deal and solvable in launch.json I would think, but I was curious about why there's that difference between running docker-compose up in a terminal on my host OS as compared to what VS Code is doing.

Thanks for any ideas anyone might have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also encountered same problem. This is a typical Ubuntu problem where the **/etc/apache2/envvars** file needs to be sourced before apache2 can start properly. 
To fix this just see the content of envars file (cat /etc/apache2/envvars), it's output will show you environment variables. Add them to your Dockerfile. In my case, I added below environment variables in my Dockerfile.

```
ENV APACHE_RUN_USER  www-data
ENV APACHE_RUN_GROUP www-data
ENV APACHE_LOG_DIR   /var/log/apache2
ENV APACHE_PID_FILE  /var/run/apache2/apache2.pid
ENV APACHE_RUN_DIR   /var/run/apache2
ENV APACHE_LOCK_DIR  /var/lock/apache2
ENV APACHE_LOG_DIR   /var/log/apache2
```

Use this image to start you container